# Cite a paper currently under review

Tags: publications, citations, paper-submission

I wrote a paper a few months ago, which I submitted to a journal and is currently under review. My field is mathematics.

Lately I have been thinking about a few things with a colleague and we came up with a small project which uses the results of my paper. The new paper is already written, and we are planning to submit it to a journal (not the same one).

The results from my paper, while obviously original, are not unexpected, and they extend previous (published) results to more general situations. This means that, at least for experts, the results themselves should be correct, so it's not something suspicious.

Is it acceptable to submit our new paper and cite the relevant results from my previous, still under review, paper? I don't think I want to wait for acceptance since it could still take a few more months and job application time is getting closer.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my paper is available online, both on my home page and the arXiv.

EDIT: In [Citing a paper under review in 2 different conferences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11540/citing-a-paper-under-review-in-2-different-conferences) there is a somewhat similar situation. I think mine is different in two aspects:

1) the fields, and hence the common practices, are generally different.
2) the second paper in question is with a second coauthor. It's out of the question to consider merging both papers into one, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to handle such a previous submission that is still under review is to create a technical report out of the previous submission, publish this report on your home page or on arxiv.org, and cite this technical report in your new paper.

In this way, reviewers can take into account the previous results without needing to have this paper published formally.

In case your previous paper gets accepted while your new paper is still under revision, you could update your new paper in a revised version.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, the paper is available both on my homepage and in the arXiv (not as a technical report, however; there is no such thing in my field).

Comment: I think in this case, you can cite directly the paper in the arXiv, maybe including a direct link to the pdf.

Comment: Yes, just cite the arXiv version. Probably, by the time your new paper is accepted, the older paper will have been, too, so you can update the citation to the published (or to-appear) version.